# "Gamers of platform" or "gamers on platform"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

We're duking it out to come up with a strapline on [meta.gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/welcome-to-qa-for-your-text-here/3104#3104). Which is correct?

> Welcome to Q&A for gamers **of** all platforms.
>
> Welcome to Q&A for gamers **on** all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an individual platform, the word **on** would be used. However, since this refers to *all* platforms, it would not be appropriate (since it would be limited to gamers who each use every platform, rather than any gamers using any platform).

They would both be correct, but have different meanings.